# Angular 8 RXJS - Make multiple HTTP calls sequentially

Tags: angular, request, rxjs, httpclient

My code is:

```
return this.creaClienti(cliente)
      .pipe(
        tap(res => console.log('Cliente ->', res)),
        concatMap(res => this.creaIntolleranza(intolleranza)),
        tap(res => console.log('Intolleranza ->', res)),
        concatMap(res => this.creaSpaziUtilizzati(utilizzoSpazi)),
        tap(res => console.log('Utilizzo spazi ->', res)),
        concatMap(res => this.creaEvento(evento))
      );
  }
```

but this.creaClienti(cliente) is:

```
 creaClienti(clienti: any[]): Observable<any> {
    return from(clienti).pipe(
      concatMap(cliente => <Observable<any>>this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + 'api/json/node/cliente', cliente, this.httpOptions))
    );
  }
```

the problem is that every time a contained call is ended the pipe restarts...

I need to run multiple call lists sequentially, all the functions that are in the concatMap are in fact similar to **creaClienti**

Comment: That sounds correct. You can append `shareReplay()` and multiple subscriptions shouldn't trigger the source Observable.

Comment: I do not want that for every call made in creaClienti it starts the pipe again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the pipe starts again? Where are you subscribing to those observables? `.subscribe` or `aync` pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want all your functions (`this.creaClienti`, `this.creaIntolleranza`, `this.creaSpaziUtilizzati`, `this.creaEvento(evento)`) to only emit once when all inner http calls completed.

If e.g. `creaClienti` should only emit once all internal calls are done you can add `last` or `toArray` depending on the output you want.

```ts
creaClienti(clienti: any[]): Observable<any> {
  return from(clienti).pipe(
    concatMap(cliente => <Observable<any>>this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + 'api/json/node/cliente', cliente, this.httpOptions)),
    last() // only emit the last http response
    // or toArray() // emit all http response in an array when the last one completed
  );
}
```